# What does & in &2 mean in PHP?

Tags: php

In the last line of the following code, it has `&2, if($page['special']&2).`

What does & mean?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))$id=(int)$_REQUEST['id'];
else $id=0;
if($id){ // check that page exists
    $page=dbRow("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id=$id");
    if($page!==false){
        $page_vars=json_decode($page['vars'],true);
        $edit=true;
    }
}
if(!isset($edit)){
    $parent=isset($_REQUEST['parent'])?(int)$_REQUEST['parent']:0;
    $special=0;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['hidden']))$special+=2;
    $page=array('parent'=>$parent,'type'=>'0','body'=>'','name'=>'','title'=>'','ord'=>0,'description'=>'','id'=>0,'keywords'=>'','special'=>$special,'template'=>'');
    $page_vars=array();
    $id=0;
    $edit=false;
}

// { if page is hidden from navigation, show a message saying that
if($page['special']&2)echo '<em>NOTE: this page is currently hidden from the front-end navigation. Use the "Advanced Options" to un-hide it.</em>';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: In the context of this question & was part of binary math, not a 'by reference' operator

Comment: @Dmitri that case is covered in the linked reference as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$page['special'] & 2
```

means

> `$page['special']` [bitwise AND](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) `2`

It basically checks to see if the 2 bit is set in `$page['special']`.

This line:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['hidden']))$special+=2;
```

explicitly adds 2 to `$special` so that it'll satisfy the bitwise AND operation and comparison, because decimal 2 == binary 10, with the 1 representing the 2<sup>1</sup> bit, ensuring it is set.

The AND operation returns 2 if the 2 bit is set, which resolves to `true` in PHP and satisfies the condition; otherwise it returns 0 which is considered `false`.

Quite a neat trick IMO, not sure how secure it is though.

Comment: Why would you want that instead of a simple, readable `&& isset($_REQUEST['hidden']);`. I may be tired now but i don't see the advantage.

Comment: @alexn: No idea either. Looks like the developer who wrote that code wanted to feel a little smart.

Comment: @alexn, ͏@BoltClock, The advantage is exactly the opposite of what you've quoted. Obfuscation is an advantage when you want to read something and at the same time don't want others to read it.

Comment: `$special+=2` doesn’t necessarly make `$special & 2` true. For example if initially `$special=2`.

Answer (score 13):

[`&` is the bitwise AND operator.](http://php.net/language.operators.bitwise) The result of `a & b` are the bits that are equal in `a` and `b`.

So in this case `$page['special']&2` returns either `0` or `2` depending on the bit pattern of `$page['special']`:

```
  **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **X*    // $page['special']
& 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010    // 2
=========================================
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00X0    // $page['special'] & 2
```

Comment: The result of `$a & $b` is a `1` for all bits that are `1` in both `$a` and `$b`. It’s not about equality.

Answer (score 8):

It's the [bitwise and operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

It looks like it's using that particular bit to hide the page.

In case you don't know what the bitwise operator is, consider the value 74 in binary:

```
0100 1010
```

If you `and` this with 2 (`0000 0010`), you get:

```
0100 1010
0000 0010
---- ----
0000 0010
```

or a non-zero (true) value.

The lines:

```
$special=0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['hidden']))$special+=2;
```

are setting that bit based on the `hidden` key.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP `&` is the bitwise operator for `AND`.

So it would `AND` the binary value of `$page['special']` with the binary value of 2, which would be:

```
0000 0010
```

So the **overall value will either be 2 or 0**.

Answer (score 0):

& is the [bitwise AND](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator.

& 2 checks whether the second bit in the special field's value is set.