# PHP if & question

Tags: php

what does this mean "if ($strength & 2) {"  in the following:
I dont understand the $ 2 part...

```
    function generatePassword($length=11, $strength=7) {
    $vowels = 'aeuy';
    $consonants = 'bdghjmnpqrstvz';
    if ($strength & 1) {
        $consonants .= 'BDGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ';
    }
    if ($strength & 2) {
        $vowels .= "AEUY";
    }
    if ($strength & 4) {
        $consonants .= '23456789';
    }
    if ($strength & 8) {
        $consonants .= '@#$%';
    }

    $password = '';
    $alt = time() % 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ($alt == 1) {
            $password .= $consonants[(rand() % strlen($consonants))];
            $alt = 0;
        } else {
            $password .= $vowels[(rand() % strlen($vowels))];
            $alt = 1;
        }
    }
    return $password;
}
```

Comment: something about bitwise operator

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does & in &2 mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705262/what-does-in-2-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is a [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). It manipulates the physical bits of a number. `&` is known as "bitwise AND". Given two numbers, it will create a new number for all of the shared bits in both numbers.

If you line up the bits for two numbers, any matching bits will be in the resulting number.

```
 7: 00000111
 2: 00000010

 7 & 2 == 2
```

This is an easy way to store information in a compact manner.

Comment: this is the best example of bitwise operations that i have seen, i finally get it. +1

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the *and* [bitwise operato](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)r.

> `$a & $b` Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set.

`$strength` appears to be an option for the strength of the password.

`2` in binary is `00000010`. If `$strength` was `2`, then it would run that condition because the resulting number would be `2` (as both bits are set the same in both numbers).

It `$strength` were `1` (`0000001`), when bitwised with `2` would produce `0`, and the condition would be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This `if ($strength & 2) {` means "if the second bit is equal to 1".
Suppose $strength = 6 or 110 in binary system, at the same time binary representation of 2 is 10. So & operator does a bitwise `and` operation:

```
110
010
=
010
```

You get positive number only when the second bit of `$strength` is equal to 1, otherwise you get 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bitwise comparison - see http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm for a basic description of what is going on.

If the author had defined some nice constants, it would read more like:

```
function generatePassword($length = 11, $strength = STRENGTH_INCLUDE_UPPERCASE & STRENGTH_INCLUDE_DIGITS & STRENGTH_INCLUDE_SYMBOLS) {
  if ($strength & STRENGTH_INCLUDE_UPPERCASE) { ...
  if ($strength & STRENGTH_INCLUDE_DIGITS) { ...
  if ($strength & STRENGTH_INCLUDE_SYMBOLS { ...
```

which would make it far more readable for you and maintainable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have used
`$vowels = 'aeuy';
$consonants = 'bdghjmnpqrstvz';`
to change
`$vowels = 'aeiou';
$consonants = 'bdghjmnpqrstvyz';`

Answer (score 0):

& is a bitwise operator. Mainly it tells you if the binary form of $strength has a 1 on position:

- 2 for 2
- 3 for 4
- 4 for 8

Answer (score 0):

the '&' is the a bitwise operator. `returns 1` not a boolean.
Well,if you are looking do a comparison use the "==" operator.

replace

```
if ($strength & 1) {
    $consonants .= 'BDGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ';
}
```

by

```
if ($strength == 1) {
    $consonants .= 'BDGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ';
}
```